# what should i do after liking an offensive picture mistakenly?

Tags: halal-haram, technology, mistake

i accidentally liked a picture that was an offensive drawing of النبي عيسى علية السلام but I wasn't aware and then i took a second look at it and looked at the caption and then i unliked it

what should I do after so? I feel like I've done a really bad thing that I might be خارج الملة

Answer (score 1):

If you have done something by mistake or unintentionally Allah might forgive you.

> Allah has forgiven for me my nation their mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do." (Sunan ibn Majah https://sunnah.com/urn/1321220 and https://sunnah.com/urn/1321240)

Nevertheless repentance is advised and you should avoid doing the same again.
A mistake or unintentional act doesn't take you out of the fold of Islam.